# What Lokas and Andas are destroyed during Naimittika and Prakrita Pralayas?

Tags: time, pralaya

1. During Naimittika Pralaya, after 1 kalpa when Brahma sleeps, I've read that 3 worlds (Bhu, Bhuvah, Suvah) are destroyed while higher lokas exist.
   What about 7 lower lokas (Atala - Patala)? Do only 3 of them get destroyed 
   (Atala, Vitala, Sutala), while other 4 exist?
2. I've read there are multiple anda-kataha, each with its own Brahma, Rudra, Indra, 14 lokas, Karya Vaikunta - basically replicas of each 'universe'. After lifetime of 'our' Brahma, during Prakrita Pralaya, our Anda gets dissolved in Prakriti.
   What happens to other Andas - are all of them created/destroyed at the same time ? If not, is there anytime when absolutely no anda exists anywhere (avyaktam) ?

Comment: I removed the part of your question about multiple Brahmandas.  You should put that in a separate question.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, why ? they are related questions - what happens during the different types of Pralaya..